# Match anything EXCEPT a sequence of periods or ellipses

Tags: python, regex

I want to use Python's `re.findall()` method to match something like the following:

> Email......@gmail.com

in the manner that I get a return value of

```
["Email", "@gmail.com"]
```

The dots can be either periods or ellipses. Preferably mixtures of such, though it probably doesn't matter too much (word processors often collapse `...` to a single Unicode ellipse character `u'\u2026'`, but say if one were left over...).

I've been trying to approach it by "match anything that isn't a sequence of ellipses and periods", but it's hard because complementing only works within `[]`!. Does anyone have any ideas?

**PROGRESS:**

I found `u"([^\u2026](?!\.\.))"`, which gives me

```
[u'E', u'-', u'M', u'a', u'i', u'l', u' ', u'a', u'd', u'd', u'r', u'e', u's', u's', u' ', u'\t', u'@', u'g', u'm', u'a', u'i', u'l', u'.', u'c', u'o', u'm']
```

Unfortunately, attempting to match these up in groups (by appending a plus at the end of the Regex) gives me `['k']`. :(

Comment: My previous comment was rather silly so I deleted it. `re.findall(ur"[^\.\u2026]+", "Email....@gmail.com")` seems to do what you want. It matches sequences of characters that are not "." or "…". Note the `u` prefix to string, which indicates it is an Unicode string and allows you to use `\u` syntax within it.

Comment: @ArturGaspar it ALMOST works! :P I've already tried this one. The problem is that it matches the "@gmail" and "com" separately; I want it to match everything that's not a /sequence/  of dots or ellipses.

Comment: @alicoder So you want to match characters that are not dots or ellipses, or, when they are, are not preceded or followed by a dot or ellipsis? `(?:[^\.\u2026]|(?:(?<=[^\.\u2026]).(?=[^\.\u2026])))+`

Comment: @ArturGaspar Perfect, but AvinashRaj got there first :P You get an upvote though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below code aslo,

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "Email......@gmail.com"
>>> re.findall(r'(?:(?=[^.]|(?<=\w)\.(?=\w)).)+', s)
['Email', '@gmail.com']
```

Idea behind here is, the above regex would match any character but not of dot one or more times. If it found a dot, then it checks for the preceding and the following character. It allows the  dot only if the preceding the and following char must be an word character.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you! I hadn't thought to say "match anything as long as it's not a dot; or if it is, ...", which allowed me to expand it to "match anything as long as it's not a dot or an ellipsis, or if it is one, ...". I've ended up with u"(?:(?=[^\u2026.]|(?<=[^\u2026.])[\u2026.](?=[^\u2026.])).)+", which seems to be just perfect. (I think it's what Artur came up with in the comments, but since you got there first with an answer you get the accept :)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pattern such as:

```
(\w+)\.{2,}(.+)
```

Below is a breakdown of what it does:

```
(       # Starts capture group 1
\w+     # Matches 1 or more word characters
)       # Closes capture group 1
\.{2,}  # Matches . 2 or more times
(       # Starts capture group 2
.+      # Matches 1 or more characters
)       # Closes capture group 2
```

And here is a demonstration:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match('(\w+)\.{2,}(.+)', 'Email......@gmail.com').groups()
('Email', '@gmail.com')
>>>
```

You'll notice too that I used `re.match` instead of `re.findall`.  `re.findall` is for finding *multiple* occurrences of a pattern in a string.  If there is only one occurrence, you should use either `re.match` (matches from the beginning) or `re.search` (matches anywhere).

If however there *are* multiple occurrences, then using `re.findall` with my pattern will return a list of tuples representing the matches:

```
>>> import re
>>> data = '''
... Email......@gmail.com
... Name.......Bob
... Email......@yahoo.com
... Name.......Joe
... '''
>>> re.findall('(\w+)\.{2,}(.+)', data)
[('Email', '@gmail.com'), ('Name', 'Bob'), ('Email', '@yahoo.com'), ('Name', 'Joe')]
>>>
```