# splitting devanagari words from each line of some given text file written in devanagari

Tags: python

I have the following text :-

जैसा तुम चाहोगे…
जैसा तुम चाहोगे…
जैसा तुम चाहोगे…
जैसा तुम चाहोगे…
जैसा तुम चाहोगे…  
जैसा तुम चाहोगे…
वैसा ही रब मिलता… 
जैसा तुम चाहोगे…
वैसा ही रब मिलता… 
जैसा तुम चाहोगे…
वैसा ही रब मिलता… 
जैसा तुम चाहोगे वैसा 
स स सत्या…
स स सत्या…
स स सत्या…
स स सत्या…
म्यान से निकलती है 
रूहों पे लगती है 
म्यान से निकलती है 
रूहों पे लगती है 
म्यान से निकलती है 
रूहों पे लगती है 
म्यान से निकलती है 
रूहों पे लगती है 
सदियों तलक फिर…
सदियों तलक फिर…
सदियों तलक फिर…
सदियों तलक फिर…
सदियों तलक फिर…
सदियों तलक ज़िन्दगी ये सुलगती है 
सदियों तलक ज़िन्दगी ये सुलगती है 
सदियों तलक ज़िन्दगी ये सुलगती है 
सदियों तलक ज़िन्दगी ये सुलगती है 
स स सत्या…
स स सत्या…
स स सत्या…
स स सत्या…
डर की हुकूमत है 
डर की ज़रुरत है 
डर की हुकूमत है 
डर की ज़रुरत है 
डर की हुकूमत है 
डर की ज़रुरत है 
डर की हुकूमत है 
डर की ज़रुरत है 
डर के ही आगे तो 
डर के ही आगे तो 
डर के ही आगे तो 
डर के ही आगे तो 
डर के ही आगे तो 
डर के ही आगे जहां खुबसूरत है 
डर के ही आगे जहां खुबसूरत है 
डर के ही आगे जहां खुबसूरत है 
डर के ही आगे जहां स स सत्या… 
स स सत्या… 
स स सत्या… 
स स सत्या… 
स स सत्या… 
स स सत्या… 
स स सत्या… 
सत्या… सत्या… सत्या… सत्या…

My task is to separate each word after removing some dots(...) and certain other punctuation marks if exists and storing those words in a new separate file using python. For this i have written this code but couldn;t able to separate '...' from certain words . please help me in this issue

code:-

```
import os
import re
import math
path='/home/priyansh/Downloads/ltrc/100/'

def split_fun(delimiters,string,maxsplit=0):
    import re
    regexpattern='|'.join(map(re.escape,delimiters))
    return re.split(regexpattern,string,maxsplit)

delim = "?","|","(",")","()",";","<",">","<>","\n",",",".","..","...","....",".....","......"," ","-"
filename="271.txt"
fd = open('sample_output.txt','w+')
with open(path+filename,'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        for j in split_fun(delim,line):
            if j!=" " and j!="":
                fd.write(j+"\n")

fd.close()
```

*Link has been provided for the output of this code along with the input file [input and output files](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B14xx1stWvMOaUFxbjBfM0pyRlk)

Comment: Apparently the three dots in the text are actually a single character (…) which is different from the three characters you are checking on your list (...). Try adding that character to the list and it should work.

Comment: yeah this i know , can u suggest or tell me some way to remove these dots and what do u mean by "Try adding that character to the list " . I mean can u elaborate more ?

Comment: @priyanshagrawal Three dots, or an ellipsis, (like this … , not like this ...) is one character. Add it to the list of strings. How to type changes depending on your system. On a mac, it is alt-;.

Comment: @SamCraig Can u tell me how to remove ellipsis from this sentence :- "जैसा तुम चाहोगे…"       I have tried what it is given in this link but nothing works , link -: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568207/match-anything-except-a-sequence-of-periods-or-ellipses

Comment: @SamCraig thank u it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should copy and paste your delim from file itself as they are Unicode.
I have copied 3 dots from the file(217.txt) and pasted in delim at the beginning.

```
import io

sourceFilePath=r'C:\Users\Sachin\Desktop\271.txt'
destinationFilePath=r'C:\Users\Sachin\Desktop\sample_output.txt'

textLinesFromFile = open(sourceFilePath, encoding="utf8").read()

delim = "…","?","|","(",")","()",";","<",">","<>","\n",",",".","..","...","....",".....","......"," ","-"
delim = list(delim)

for i in range (0,len(delim)):
    textLinesFromFile = textLinesFromFile.replace(delim[i], " ")

with io.open(destinationFilePath, 'w', encoding="utf8") as file:
    file.write(textLinesFromFile)
```